# Email sending in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Please, can you help me. How can i send emails from localhost in devise. For example i write in development enviroment

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

But it doesn't send emails on my address for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to setup an initializer for you to send email in development enviroment.

Place this configuration in: config/initializers/mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "username",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

*NOTE: This configuration is for Gmail,if you are not using Gmail you will need to modify the setting for your SMTP client.*

Remember that you need to restart your server after adding this file to your rails app.

There is also a great Railscast episode tha will help you [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 0):

```
#this works well
add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string

#But this cannot work !!!
add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string, :null => false, :default => ''
add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime, :null => false, :default => '1970-01-01'
add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime, :null => false, :default => '1970-01-01'
add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string, :null => false, :default => ''
```

See this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2567

> I catch an issue today and I spend 5 hours on it.
>   Devise 's confirmation email cannot work when the confirmation_token relational columns is blank. Well when the columns is null it works well.